# Phoenix PubSub event firing multiple times

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

```
  def join("world:lobby", _message, socket) do
    PubSub.subscribe(Rotb.PubSub, "zone_1")

    {:ok, socket}
  end


  def handle_info(%{message: message}, socket) do
    broadcast(socket, "shout", %{"socket_id" => socket.id, "message" => message})

    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_in("shout", payload, socket) do
    PubSub.broadcast(Rotb.PubSub, "zone_1", %{
      message: payload["message"]
    })

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

However the shout event happens multiple times on my client? It looks like it might appear an additional time for each other connection but not 100%.

Comment: You didn’t show the code of your `broadcast/3` function, but if it corresponds to its name, each client is about to receive this message and then their `handle_in/3` are to be executed.

Comment: When I print 
self() 
in handle in I get duplicate pids! How does that happen
#PID<0.704.0>
#PID<0.641.0>
#PID<0.641.0>
#PID<0.704.0>

Comment: Also the broadcast is PubSub.broadcast right? That's a function I take from Phoenix

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin the broadcast/3 is from Phoenix.Channel - https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#broadcast/3

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are doing, you want all connected clients to the phoenix channel to get the shout.

The PubSub subscription there makes sense.

The broadcast in handle info does not make sense because its for the current client. You should just be doing a push there. See your code below with screenshot of a React Native console with two clients connected.

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.TestChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel

  alias Phoenix.PubSub

  def join("world:lobby", _message, socket) do
    PubSub.subscribe(MyApp.PubSub, "zone_1")

    {:ok, socket}
  end

  def handle_info(%{message: message}, socket) do
    IO.inspect({"NEW MESSAGE", message})
    push(socket, "shout", %{"socket_id" => socket.id, "message" => message})

    {:noreply, socket}
  end

  def handle_in("shout", payload, socket) do
    IO.inspect({"SHOUT", payload})

    PubSub.broadcast(MyApp.PubSub, "zone_1", %{
      message: payload["message"]
    })

    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

[image]

The shout is sent from the android client. If you have two clients connected then you should see two different pids for each socket.

Now if you are just trying to broadcast the message to all connected clients, you should just use the **broadcast/3** inside **handle_in** and don't use PubSub. PubSub is for pushing messages from outside the socket. Like some cron job that finds if some other external state has changed then pushes that to the clients. For broadcasting messages from one client to others then **broadcast/3** inside **handle_in** is enough

Using broadcast inside handle_info with pubsub means all clients get the pubsub then they all broadcast. No what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please check to see if you are calling `subscribe` function in your `mount` function in the LiveView.

The `mount` function is called twice, and duplicate subscriptions will result in  duplicate events being sent to `handle_info`.

Comment: The code shared is for phoenix channels which use PubSub anyway. mount is a liveview function or those sorts.